# import a single getServerSideProps method to multiple pages in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, next.js, es6-modules

I'm trying to import the getServerSideProps method from this page to another and use it throughout multiple pages. How can I do that?

Heres my code:

```
import DashboardLayout from "@app/layout/DashboardLayout";
import Overview from "@containers/dashboard/Overview";
import { parsedCookie } from "@infrastructure/utils/functions";

const OverviewPage = () => {
  return (
    <DashboardLayout>
      <Overview />
    </DashboardLayout>
  );
};

export default OverviewPage;

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const token = parsedCookie(context.req);
  const { accessToken, refreshToken } = token;
  if (!accessToken || !refreshToken) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
};
```

Comment: Put this function in a separate file and import it wherever you need it.

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer . heres how you can use a pages datafetching method on a another page

```
import DashboardLayout from "@app/layout/DashboardLayout";
import MyCourses from "@containers/dashboard/MyCourses";
import { getServerSideProps } from "../index";

const MyCoursesPage = () => {
  return (
    <DashboardLayout>
      <MyCourses />
    </DashboardLayout>
  );
};

export default MyCoursesPage;

export { getServerSideProps };
```

Comment: This is incorrect. This prop is not usable in any component. This is specifically designed for pages

Comment: @abhikumar22 You're correct that `getServerSideProps` can't be used outside page components, but the OP didn't mention "any component", he specifically said _"use a pages data fetching method on another **page**"_ (emphasis is mine).

Comment: Thanks! I had the same question to prevent logged in users from accessing login/signup pages in my small project. Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can not import `getServerSideProps` they are unique for each page but if all pages in first load should get same data you can add `getIntialProps` in your `_app.js` file.
for more info you can read
[customizing _app.js files](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic function where you can pass the page which you want to used and fetch data according that prop. i.e

In the NextJs page you can use like this

```
export const getStaticProps = createGetStaticProps("home")
```

and the method can be created like this

```
export function createGetStaticProps(
  page: PageType,
): GetStaticProps<any> {
  const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<any> = async (context) => {
  // Load any data related to page  
  const data = await loadData(page, context.params)

    return {
      props: serializeStaticProps(data),
      revalidate: 5000,
    }
  }

  return getStaticProps
}
```